# Could not read new properties from ConfigServer

Tags: yaml, spring-cloud-config-server

For my apps I have ConfigServer that serves application.yml properties. I added new @Value to my app and new properties for yml:

```
 @Value("${sms-service.oauth-token}")
    private String OAUTH_TOKEN;
    @Value("${sms-service.proxy-address")
    private String PROXY_ADDRESS;
```

in yaml:

```
sms-service:
  oauth-token: xxx
  proxy-address: https://api.com/
```

It read all other properties but not it. I saved this yaml file, commited it and nothing.